# Power Apps Flow, alternative for Loops

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, lowcode

this is my first task regarding Microsoft Power App and don't know how I should solve it.
We have a flow that in the input is entered email address and as output we should get back an ID.
Both the files are in Database and basically , only the entered email address should be searched and corresponding ID should be output.
What we have here right now is a loop. But a loop could lead to problems if we have multiple data. The question is, what could we use instead of loop that leads to the same answer.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only retrieve one (or a couple) of columns of a list of values you could use a Select instead of a apply to each loop.

Below is an example for one column.
*I used the Account table with the accountid column in this example*

1. Switch the Map field to text mode and select your column name.

[image]

2. After that you could even join the values with for example a comma character in a Compose action by using the expression below.

   join(body('Select'), ',')